# Infering parameter type based on a different parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm wondering if it's possible to infer a parameter, based on another one when using `array.map()`.

I have a component like this `<List items={cards} renderItem={renderItem} />` that just maps the items, and just passes each item to the renderItem function. I'd like the `renderItem = (card) => {}` below to be of the type of each `cards` item (In my case `CardDomainModel`).

So far I have this:

```
import { Group, ListSkeleton } from 'components'
import React, { FC, ReactElement } from 'react'

interface IList<T> {
  isLoading?: boolean
  items: T[]
  renderItem: (item: T) => ReactElement
}

/*
---
This (T) `any` must be of whatever type `items` is?
---
*/
export const List: FC<IList<any>> = ({ items, renderItem, isLoading }) => {
  if (isLoading) {
    return <ListSkeleton />
  }

  return (
    <Group spacing={2} direction="vertical">
      {items.map((item) => renderItem(item))}
    </Group>
  )
}
```

and

```
import { CardListItem, List } from 'components'
import { CardDomainModel } from 'models'
import React, { FC, memo } from 'react'

interface ICardListView {
  cards: CardDomainModel[]
}
/*
---
I want this `card` paramter to be `CardDomainModel`, inferred from `items={cards}`
---
*/
const renderItem = (card) => {
  return (
    <CardListItem
      key={card.id}
      name={card.cardholderName}
      last4={card.last4}
      currentSpending={card.currentSpending}
      limit={card.limit}
      status={card.cardStatus}
      lastTransactionDate="2015851-24"
    />
  )
}

export const CardList: FC<ICardListView> = memo(({ cards }) => {
  return <List items={cards} renderItem={renderItem} />
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there could be automatic inference there, what you should do is type the card parameter of renderItem function to CardDomainModel and typescript will automatically check if the renderItem argument matches the item type

Comment: Ye that's what I was doing atm. Thanks :)